# Can anyone recommend a good hiking trail in Scotland?

Tags: europe, recommendations, hiking, scotland

I'm looking for some info on a scenic walking tour in Scotland, preferably a walking tour that could be done in 5-7 days.

Comment: As in a long distance hiking trail? Or a 5 day Munro-bagger (aiming for several mountains per day)? Or a very gentle and flat route with just a handful of miles per day?

Comment: A moderate route, with some flat and some hills. I don't have a problem doing 10 miles a day or so. Not sure if there is a trail like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:
http://www.capewrathtrail.co.uk/

You could do it in stages. It's really tough in places but the scenery is fantastic.

Comment: I second @william's comment that this is really tough.  It's normally takes a bit over a fortnight.  It's often described as "Britain's toughest trail" and passes through one of the least populated parts of Europe.  You'll need to plan carefully where to buy provisions as you cannot rely on passing a shop every day, and you'll almost certainly need to wild-camp some nights.  But the scenery is truly stunning, far more so than the infinitely more popular West Highland Way.  The link provided is now dead, but this one may help: http://www.walkhighlands.co.uk/cape-wrath-trail.shtml

Answer (score 11):

The most obvious is the oldest long distance walk in Scotland: The West Highland Way. It starts in the north of Glasgow City and walks cross country, mostly off road but on good paths, north to Fort William. It is about 96 miles long and can be completed in 4-8 days depending on your level of fitness, determination and of course weather. This route takes you through some of the very best of Scotland's scenery including Loch Lomond, Rannoch Moor, Glen Coe and finishing near Ben Nevis. Accommodation on route can be camping, youth hostels, B&B or a mix of these.

For more info see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Highland_Way
- http://www.west-highland-way.co.uk/

[image: West Highland Way route map]

Other long distance walks in Scotland include The Great Glen Way, Southern Upland Way and Speyside Way. However, I'd only consider them after the West Highland Way.

Comment: Oh cool! What's the best time of year to go? Is there a rainy season?

Comment: The rainy season in Scotland is often jokingly said to be 1st January - 31st December... The western highlands do get the brunt of it, so pack for damp weather all year round

Comment: Very helpful! Since I checked out average rainfall and it was a little more forgiving than you estimate! Rain gear it is!

Comment: And we are expecting snow shower in highlands this weekend... :)